# Using render.option_create in Angular Selectize prevents adding new items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selectize.js

I'm trying to localize a selectize input ([Angular Selectize](https://github.com/machineboy2045/angular-selectize)) box in an Angular app. When I add `option_create` in selectize's config, the newly created localized formatting shows up ok, but it fails to add new items.

So, with this config the selectize input **does not add** items:

```
$scope.myConfig = {
  create: true,
  render: {
    option_create: function (data, escape) {
      return '<div>MY_ADD' + ': <strong>' + escape(data.input) + '</strong></div>';
    }
  }
}
```

but this works:

```
config = {
  create: true
}
```

[See the plunker demonstrating this](http://plnkr.co/edit/P2RUKXX1MlNc71j8WOMH?p=preview).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `create` class was missing in the returned div.

This works:

```
return '<div class="create">MY_ADD' + ': <strong>' + 
  escape(data.input) + '</strong></div>';
```